# Space between tables in html e-mail on iPhone 7

Tags: html-email, ios10

Has anyone noticed the following rendering bug in iOS 10 for html email: Spacing between tables ...

[image]

Does anyone have any tips as how to resolve?

Comment: If you show us the code you use it will be easier for us to provide an answer. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does your code look like and what client?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice beginning layout that will work with nearly all mail clients:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:title" content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*">
<title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  body{
   width:100% !important;
   min-width:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  td{
   border-collapse:collapse !important;
  }
  v*{
   behavior:url(#default#VML);
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
  a img{
   border:none;
  }
  img{
   display:block;
  }
  table{
   border-spacing:0;
   border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  p{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   font-size:100%;
   line-height:1.2em;
   font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
        #wrappertable{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:100% !important;
   line-height:100% !important;
  }
        @media screen and (max-width:480px){
       table {
        width:100% !important;
       }

       }
      </style>
  </head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" offset="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding: 0 !important; margin:0 !important;">
 <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="wrappertable">
       <tr>
           <td align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="620">
                 <tr>
                     <td width="618" align="center">
                          <!--THIS IS THE CONTENT TABLE-->
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">
                              <tr>
                                  <td align="center">
                                    <p>Place some text here</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The important things to note here are the **INLINE BODY TAGS** and the **WRAPPER TABLE INLINE TAGS** which contain all the padding and margin resets. Make sure you always add in the `style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;"` to your first table, as that will close those gaps between the table cells.

I hope this helps!